# Objc how to compare current with previous double values in a tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, compare, double

I have a tableview that gets refreshed every 10 sec with new double values and i need a mechanism to compare current with previous values but i jam not doing it correctly.

this is what i have now. Can you please propose how to store the current/previous values to get compare after refresh. thx in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierCell];
    }

    Value = [[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"value"] doubleValue];
    if (ValueCurrent > ValuePrevious && ValuePrevious !=0.0) {
        Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    if (ValueCurrent < ValuePrevious) {
        Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    ValuePrevious = Value; 


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the wrong place for any logic not directly related to the display of cells. In particular `ValuePrevious = Value;` is absolutely wrong in that location. And please change all your variables to start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

On my mind all such checks should be performed on model level - in tempDictionary in your case. Add one more key "changed" and set it to @(YES) if new value is different from the previous one when dictionary is updated and to @(NO) otherwise.

Then you can check this value in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and set up background color.

Comment: I agree this is the best thing to do. I will try to do so and see how it goes. Though i am guessing there should exist a more simple way.... Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure if you need to compare new values of each cell to its previous. If you need to compare new value with previous value respective to each cell then you have to create an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` separately for previous and current values, then compare them each with respective to each cell.

And if you would like to compare only one value when `UITableView` reloads then you shouldn't compare it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead compare it when you call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you i know it should exist in a lower level the check but i have bot yet figure it out completely. thank you